# Nodejs mssql recordset return null

Tags: node.js, sql-server

[image]
I'm using mssql module in Nodejs,

it seem like request query works fine, because rowsAffected value is
same in server record value.

but recordset and recordsets value always return null.

it's anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Aside... I would strongly discourage the use of Template Literals when invoking queries. Otherwise it's all too easy to create SQL Injection attacks as demonstrated on the [node-mssql page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) with `const result = await sql.query\`select * from mytable where id = ${value}\``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change config.stream to false.

If you enable streaming, you don't receive data with method query(). In this case you must listen for events to receive data, as explained in the docs:

https://tediousjs.github.io/node-mssql/#streaming

Streaming should be used when you expect a large amount of rows.

Comment: Hello, mozway. Actually, the answer that solves the problem is in the first line. If I remove the external link, would this answer be appropriate?

Comment: I think the link is fine, but you could give more details, such as why the configuration change is needed.